# Is it possible to write in input buffer passed into function more than was expected? (no stack overflow)

Tags: c++, c, buffer, recv

I doing some packet translation patch.
My dll injects into Chinese game, hooks recv, listen for packets and translates strings received in Chinese.
I was coding and coding and coding... Until I found out how I supposed to write in buf more than the packet length?

```
int __stdcall Hooked_recv(SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags)
{
    h_recv.PreHook();

    int ret_val = recv(s, buf, len, flags);
//ret_val is the number of bytes received. Ok, I can increase it, but...
//what to do with buf? Sure I can write there as much as no access violation appears.
//but I need a safe way.
//I guess if I do buf = new char[NEW_SIZE] then caller will fail to read buf because of pointer changed?
//what could I do to make received packet longer?
//I no want to reverse exe and increase buffer in hex editor. at least for now.

    h_recv.PostHook();

    return ret_val;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fill the buffer as much as you can. If you have any leftover, save it for the next call to your hooked receive function (put that first, if that fills it, repeat saving the new leftover). You will need to use a buffer, that's unavoidable.

Comment: I don't know buf size. All I can do is to fill it till access violation. maybe there is someway to scan whole process memory for a pointer to buf and modify it?

Comment: The purpose of `len` is to tell you how many bytes you can put in the buffer.

Comment: But buf comes with predefined size. ppls declare some char* buf[1024] and pass it to recv function. Only after recv called they know how much bytes actually received. buf size never changes.

Comment: my bad :( you are right. didn't noticed the meaning of len

Comment: Correct solution, but it may be important to point out that you should avoid forwarding to the underlying `recv` in case you have sufficient buffered data to satisfy the call. The risk is that the buffer may grow unbounded if the translation adds extra data. E.g. assume that the hook adds one byte to every 1KB received. This will slowly grow the buffer, but after reading 1 GB the buffer will contain 1 MB. The proper solution is to return just the buffer on the 1025th call.

Comment: @MSalters Actually, it's probably easier just to pass a smaller value to the underlying `recv`. But either way, a proper implementation has to be prepared to handle the case where the buffer is already full. Imagine if you keep getting called with `len` set to 1. (Actually, doing it exactly right is subtle, because the underlying receive function may block indefinitely if you're not careful.)